# Vue Material CSS displays bad

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-material

i'm starting on Vue and i have a little problem displaying the CSS of material components. They doesn't recognize all the classes even if they're present on the final html renderized.

This is my main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import VueMaterial from 'vue-material';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueMaterial);

import 'dependency_manifest';

import App from 'components/app.vue';

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [{
    name:      'carListings.index',
    path:      '/avisos',
    component: {template: '<p>Listado</p>'}
  }, {
    name:      'carListings.show',
    path:      '/avisos/:id',
    component: {template: '<p>Detalle</p>'}
  }]
});

Vue.material.registerTheme({
  default: {
    primary: 'blue',
    accent: 'red'
  },
  green: {
    primary: 'green',
    accent: 'pink'
  },
  orange: {
    primary: 'orange',
    accent: 'green'
  },
});

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
  saveScrollPosition: true
})
  .$mount('#app-wrapper');
```

and this is my app.vue

```
    <template>
 <div>
  <md-toolbar>
    <md-button class="md-icon-button">
      <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
    </md-button>

    <h2 class="md-title" style="flex: 1">Default</h2>

    <md-button class="md-icon-button">
      <md-icon>favorite</md-icon>
    </md-button>
  </md-toolbar>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
  }
</script>
```

I'm using brunch to render it on a server. Thanks for your time!

EDIT: i'll leave an imagen showing how it's display

[image: Looks bad]

EDIT 2 : i've tried to add the CSS on differents places. first on the main.js but the console display this error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.css' from 'main.js'`

```
import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.css';
```

this add all the .css on my vendor.css, but doesn't work
then i tried to add here a cdn: index.static.jade

```
html
  head
    title Frontend developer test app
  body
    #app-wrapper
    script(src='/vendor.js')
    script(src='/app.js')
    link(href='https://unpkg.com/vue-material@0.7.2/dist/vue-material.css')
    link(href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic', rel='stylesheet')
    link(href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons', rel='stylesheet')
```

Also i tried to add here the vendor.css with all its content but still doesn't work

Comment: Where are you including the vue-material css file

Comment: @EricGuan i've edited my post for your question